# Unable to make customer payment in Netsuite via script for an invoice which has exceeded the 10000 range

Tags: netsuite, payment

I want to make payment for a particular invoice via a script
I have the customer and amount details.
I have set the customer and I am using findSublistLineWithValue API to find that Invoice line but as it had exceeded the 10000 line limit for customer payments it was not available in the list.

From UI if we customize the form to add additional filters like date, the results are getting reduced, but how to achieve this via script?

Comment: as I understood, you need to apply the same filters as you do in the UI, but in your script. So at least share the code of your script, where you have the 10,000 lines